# Creating a third dropdown menu based on the selections from the first two

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I recently started putting together what I hope to be a series of dropdown menus. The contents of each one - besides the first - is determined by the selection made in the preceding dropdown menu.

I have managed so far to get the first two working, and I'm very fine with that. Now I have hit a dead end. I can't figure out how to get the third dropdown menu to appear as a result of a selection from the second.

What I have so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$("#product").change ( function () {
    var targID  = $(this).val ();
    $("div.style-sub-1").hide ();
    $('#' + targID).show ();
} )
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_custom" id="style_container_div">
<label>Product: </label><select size="1" id="product" class=" validate['required']" title="" type="select" name="style">
<option value="">Select product</option>
<option value="01">A</option>
<option value="02">B</option>
<option value="03">C</option>
<option value="04">D</option>
<option value="05">E</option>
</select><div class="clear"></div><div id="error-message-style"></div></div>

<div id="01"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
  <label>Select a module: </label>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select module</option> 
      <option value="01">1</option>
      <option value="02">2</option>
      <option value="03">3</option>
      <option value="04">4</option>
      <option value="05">5</option>
      <option value="06">6</option>        </select>
</div>

<div id="02"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
  <label>Select a module: </label>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select module</option> 
      <option value="01">1</option>
      <option value="02">2</option>
      <option value="03">3</option>
      <option value="04">4</option>
      <option value="05">5</option>
      <option value="06">6</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="###"  class="style-sub-1"  style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
  <label>###</label> 
    <select>
      <option value="01">###</option>
      <option value="02">###</option>
      <option value="03">###</option>
      <option value="04">###</option>
    </select>
</div><div class="clear"></div><div id="error-message-style-sub-1"></div></div>



</body>


</html>
```

Selecting one of the options from `div id="01"` should lead to a third dropdown menu, and the same with any of the other second-dropdown option selections.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the last level drop down, you can give it an `id` and do the following:

```
$('.style-sub-1 select').change(function(){
    console.log('change');
    $('#lastDropdown').parent().show();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2gSVe/)

But seriously, why are you giving id's such as `###`? i don't think it's a valid `id` at all.

Why have you specified the class `style-sub-1` of second level drop down contains for last level as well..?

Why are you using inline styles when you've already specified classes..?
couldn't resist myself from saying that the `HTML` is a mess which doesn't make any sense...

Comment: It has honestly been around ten years since I last tried coding in any form! I tend to leave redundant code in so long as the rest works. I've never had a 'feel' for coding, my method is somewhat soviet in that I'll throw everything at the screen, purge anything that is obviously subversive and overcompensation is nothing to be ashamed of.

Comment: I nearly forgot to add: thanks! You helped me find what I was after.

Comment: Damn, I wrote too soon. I've been playing around with the coding and it turns out I haven't got what I thought I had. 
The idea is that the selection from the first dropdown gives me a specific set of options in the second dropdown, and the selection from the second dropdown gives me a specific set of options in the third and final dropdown. 
The way things stand everything is somewhat disjointed.